# Xqual and Junit : parameters?

Tags: java, junit

I have a problem with **Xqual** and **Junit**.

I want to test servlet responses from different servers. (Integration, Test, Prod, Development (localhost)) and **I have to use Xqual**

With success, I launch a junit test from Xqual. But without parameters.

I want to permit to the user, before launching the test, to choose the IP from server to test and since this afternoon I find nothing about this...

Is this possible? If so, how? Or do you know some tweak/others ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different ways to do that but I would advise taking advantage of the "test attributes".
You can create an attribute "ipaddress" (root node of the test tree). Ensure you create it as a dynamic attribute (this way you can change it at run time). Set this attribute to the test.

When the user creates the session he can then change the value of "ipaddress".

The attribute is passed to the junit launcher so you can slightly change your JUnit launcher to take advantage of the value of this attribute and pass it to JUnit.

If you prefer configuring this at the testcase level instead of test, then you can use the "params" instead of the "attributes"